# Postman truncate request param

Tags: url

We are receiving request from one of our clients. They send encrypted request param. Sometimes the encrypted param ends with + or =. When I try to use the same and do testing in my local with Postman. The request param received doesn't have + or = at the end. Does postman have a tendency to remove special characters from request param while sending.

Backend is Spring Controller.

Any knowledge in the matter is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Sameekshya

Comment: If the `+` or `=` is part of a request parameter it needs to be encoded. A `+` is the character for a whitespace and `=` is a marker for key/values. So you need to be sure that the parameters are encoded before sending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to url-encode those characters:

`"+"` becomes `"%2B"`

`"="` becomes `"%3D"`

See the reference for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP